# Como converter número em float para número por extenso no PHP?

Tags: php

Existe alguma função nativa, ou outra forma prática, para pegar um número em `float` e converter para o número por extenso?

Exemplo:

```
//input: 2.000,00
//output: dois mil
```

Comment: Não existe, mas deve ter por aí alguma que alguém fez, provavelmente mal feita, mas deve funcionar. Mas é muito raro querer o extenso de um número com ponto flutuante, será que é isso mesmo que quer?

Comment: por padrão acredito que não, mas ha varios fontes na internet que se propoem a fazer isso, de uma olhada aqui http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/conversao-de-valor-numerico-para-extenso-em-php e pesquisa no google antes de posta aqui no forum

Comment: http://www.dirceuresende.com/blog/escrevendo-numero-por-extenso-no-php/

Comment: @CristianUrbainski Esse é um conteúdo interessante para o site. Te recomendo ler [isso](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4026). Aliás, o [Stack Overflow em Português não é um fórum](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068).

Comment: Relacionado sobre o algoritmo: [Como modificar função VBA para escrever por extenso um número superior a 1 trilhão em célula do EXCEL?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93185/91)

Comment: Além das respostas abaixo, é interessante [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/253166/20363) em questão duplicada. Ela explica o uso da classe [`NumberFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) do pacote `intl` do PHP. Me parece uma solução mais "canônica".

Answer (score 13):

Função nativa não existe, mas aí vai uma implementação recursiva.

```
<?php

function convert_number_to_words($number) {

    $hyphen      = '-';
    $conjunction = ' e ';
    $separator   = ', ';
    $negative    = 'menos ';
    $decimal     = ' ponto ';
    $dictionary  = array(
        0                   => 'zero',
        1                   => 'um',
        2                   => 'dois',
        3                   => 'três',
        4                   => 'quatro',
        5                   => 'cinco',
        6                   => 'seis',
        7                   => 'sete',
        8                   => 'oito',
        9                   => 'nove',
        10                  => 'dez',
        11                  => 'onze',
        12                  => 'doze',
        13                  => 'treze',
        14                  => 'quatorze',
        15                  => 'quinze',
        16                  => 'dezesseis',
        17                  => 'dezessete',
        18                  => 'dezoito',
        19                  => 'dezenove',
        20                  => 'vinte',
        30                  => 'trinta',
        40                  => 'quarenta',
        50                  => 'cinquenta',
        60                  => 'sessenta',
        70                  => 'setenta',
        80                  => 'oitenta',
        90                  => 'noventa',
        100                 => 'cento',
        200                 => 'duzentos',
        300                 => 'trezentos',
        400                 => 'quatrocentos',
        500                 => 'quinhentos',
        600                 => 'seiscentos',
        700                 => 'setecentos',
        800                 => 'oitocentos',
        900                 => 'novecentos',
        1000                => 'mil',
        1000000             => array('milhão', 'milhões'),
        1000000000          => array('bilhão', 'bilhões'),
        1000000000000       => array('trilhão', 'trilhões'),
        1000000000000000    => array('quatrilhão', 'quatrilhões'),
        1000000000000000000 => array('quinquilhão', 'quinquilhões')
    );

    if (!is_numeric($number)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (($number >= 0 && (int) $number < 0) || (int) $number < 0 - PHP_INT_MAX) {
        // overflow
        trigger_error(
            'convert_number_to_words só aceita números entre ' . PHP_INT_MAX . ' à ' . PHP_INT_MAX,
            E_USER_WARNING
        );
        return false;
    }

    if ($number < 0) {
        return $negative . convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
    }

    $string = $fraction = null;

    if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
        list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
    }

    switch (true) {
        case $number < 21:
            $string = $dictionary[$number];
            break;
        case $number < 100:
            $tens   = ((int) ($number / 10)) * 10;
            $units  = $number % 10;
            $string = $dictionary[$tens];
            if ($units) {
                $string .= $conjunction . $dictionary[$units];
            }
            break;
        case $number < 1000:
            $hundreds  = floor($number / 100)*100;
            $remainder = $number % 100;
            $string = $dictionary[$hundreds];
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $conjunction . convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
        default:
            $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
            $numBaseUnits = (int) ($number / $baseUnit);
            $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
            if ($baseUnit == 1000) {
                $string = convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[1000];
            } elseif ($numBaseUnits == 1) {
                $string = convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit][0];
            } else {
                $string = convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit][1];
            }
            if ($remainder) {
                $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
                $string .= convert_number_to_words($remainder);
            }
            break;
    }

    if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
        $string .= $decimal;
        $words = array();
        foreach (str_split((string) $fraction) as $number) {
            $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
        }
        $string .= implode(' ', $words);
    }

    return $string;
}

echo '<pre>';

echo "123456789\n";
echo convert_number_to_words(123456789);
echo "\n\n";

echo "123456789.123\n";
echo convert_number_to_words(123456789.123);
echo "\n\n";

echo "-1922685.477\n";
echo convert_number_to_words(-1922685.477);
echo "\n\n";

echo "123456789123.12345\n";
echo convert_number_to_words(123456789123.12345); // rounds the fractional part
echo "\n\n";

echo "123456789123.12345\n";
echo convert_number_to_words('123456789123.12345'); // does not round

echo '</pre>';
```

Função adaptada de http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/

Answer (score 9):

Não existe uma  função nativa do php para isto, até por que ela necessitaria de um i18n para poder descrever por extenso valores de outras linguagens, acredito que o mais aconselhável nesse caso é utilizar uma classe para isto,  em [ExtremoConhecimento](http://extremoconhecimento.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/valor-por-extenso-com-php.html)  tem uma função que resolve este problema.

**Exemplo:**

```
class Monetary {

  private static $unidades = array("um", "dois", "três", "quatro", "cinco", "seis", "sete", "oito", "nove", "dez", "onze", "doze",
    "treze", "quatorze", "quinze", "dezesseis", "dezessete", "dezoito", "dezenove");
  private static $dezenas = array("dez", "vinte", "trinta", "quarenta", "cinqüenta", "sessenta", "setenta", "oitenta", "noventa");
  private static $centenas = array("cem", "duzentos", "trezentos", "quatrocentos", "quinhentos",
    "seiscentos", "setecentos", "oitocentos", "novecentos");
  private static $milhares = array(
    array("text" => "mil", "start" => 1000, "end" => 999999, "div" => 1000),
    array("text" => "milhão", "start" => 1000000, "end" => 1999999, "div" => 1000000),
    array("text" => "milhões", "start" => 2000000, "end" => 999999999, "div" => 1000000),
    array("text" => "bilhão", "start" => 1000000000, "end" => 1999999999, "div" => 1000000000),
    array("text" => "bilhões", "start" => 2000000000, "end" => 2147483647, "div" => 1000000000)
  );

  const MIN = 0.01;
  const MAX = 2147483647.99;
  const MOEDA = " real ";
  const MOEDAS = " reais ";
  const CENTAVO = " centavo ";
  const CENTAVOS = " centavos ";

  static
  function numberToExt($number, $moeda = true) {
    if ($number >= self::MIN && $number <= self::MAX) {
      $value = self::conversionR((int) $number);
      if ($moeda) {
        if (floor($number) == 1) {
          $value. = self::MOEDA;
        } else if (floor($number) > 1)
          $value. = self::MOEDAS;
      }

      $decimals = self::extractDecimals($number);
      if ($decimals > 0.00) {
        $decimals = round($decimals * 100);
        $value. = " e ".self::conversionR($decimals);
        if ($moeda) {
          if ($decimals == 1) {
            $value. = self::CENTAVO;
          } else if ($decimals > 1)
            $value. = self::CENTAVOS;
        }
      }
    }
    return trim($value);
  }

  private static
  function extractDecimals($number) {
    return $number - floor($number);
  }

  static
  function conversionR($number) {
    if (in_array($number, range(1, 19))) {
      $value = self::$unidades[$number - 1];
    } else if (in_array($number, range(20, 90, 10))) {
      $value = self::$dezenas[floor($number / 10) - 1].
      " ";
    } else if (in_array($number, range(21, 99))) {
      $value = self::$dezenas[floor($number / 10) - 1].
      " e ".self::conversionR($number % 10);
    } else if (in_array($number, range(100, 900, 100))) {
      $value = self::$centenas[floor($number / 100) - 1].
      " ";
    } else if (in_array($number, range(101, 199))) {
      $value = ' cento e '.self::conversionR($number % 100);
    } else if (in_array($number, range(201, 999))) {
      $value = self::$centenas[floor($number / 100) - 1].
      " e ".self::conversionR($number % 100);
    } else {
      foreach(self::$milhares as $item) {
        if ($number >= $item['start'] && $number <= $item['end']) {
          $value = self::conversionR(floor($number / $item['div'])).
          " ".$item['text'].
          " ".self::conversionR($number % $item['div']);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return $value;
  }

}

echo Monetary::numberToExt(500.00);
```

Entrada:

```
echo Monetary::numberToExt(500.00);
```

Saida:

```
quinhentos reais
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas o codigo contem bugs para valor de 100, abaixo de 0.99 e alguns numeros acima de mil

Answer (score 2):

Fonte: https://recursosdophp.blogspot.com.br/2012/04/ola-seguidores-do-php-bom-eu-fiz.html

Essa foi a melhor função que eu achei.
Pode testar com todos os valores possíveis, se encontrar um erro, avisa ai.

```
function extenso($valor = 0, $maiusculas = false) {
    if(!$maiusculas){
        $singular = ["centavo", "real", "mil", "milhão", "bilhão", "trilhão", "quatrilhão"];
        $plural = ["centavos", "reais", "mil", "milhões", "bilhões", "trilhões", "quatrilhões"];
        $u = ["", "um", "dois", "três", "quatro", "cinco", "seis",  "sete", "oito", "nove"];
    }else{
        $singular = ["CENTAVO", "REAL", "MIL", "MILHÃO", "BILHÃO", "TRILHÃO", "QUADRILHÃO"];
        $plural = ["CENTAVOS", "REAIS", "MIL", "MILHÕES", "BILHÕES", "TRILHÕES", "QUADRILHÕES"];
        $u = ["", "um", "dois", "TRÊS", "quatro", "cinco", "seis",  "sete", "oito", "nove"];
    }

    $c = ["", "cem", "duzentos", "trezentos", "quatrocentos", "quinhentos", "seiscentos", "setecentos", "oitocentos", "novecentos"];
    $d = ["", "dez", "vinte", "trinta", "quarenta", "cinquenta", "sessenta", "setenta", "oitenta", "noventa"];
    $d10 = ["dez", "onze", "doze", "treze", "quatorze", "quinze", "dezesseis", "dezesete", "dezoito", "dezenove"];

    $z = 0;
    $rt = "";

    $valor = number_format($valor, 2, ".", ".");
    $inteiro = explode(".", $valor);
    for($i=0;$i<count($inteiro);$i++)
    for($ii=strlen($inteiro[$i]);$ii<3;$ii++)
    $inteiro[$i] = "0".$inteiro[$i];

    $fim = count($inteiro) - ($inteiro[count($inteiro)-1] > 0 ? 1 : 2);
    for ($i=0;$i<count($inteiro);$i++) {
        $valor = $inteiro[$i];
        $rc = (($valor > 100) && ($valor < 200)) ? "cento" : $c[$valor[0]];
        $rd = ($valor[1] < 2) ? "" : $d[$valor[1]];
        $ru = ($valor > 0) ? (($valor[1] == 1) ? $d10[$valor[2]] : $u[$valor[2]]) : "";

        $r = $rc.(($rc && ($rd || $ru)) ? " e " : "").$rd.(($rd &&
        $ru) ? " e " : "").$ru;
        $t = count($inteiro)-1-$i;
        $r .= $r ? " ".($valor > 1 ? $plural[$t] : $singular[$t]) : "";
        if ($valor == "000")$z++; elseif ($z > 0) $z--;
        if (($t==1) && ($z>0) && ($inteiro[0] > 0)) $r .= (($z>1) ? " de " : "").$plural[$t];
        if ($r) $rt = $rt . ((($i > 0) && ($i <= $fim) && ($inteiro[0] > 0) && ($z < 1)) ? ( ($i < $fim) ? ", " : " e ") : " ") . $r;
    }

    if(!$maiusculas){
        $return = $rt ? $rt : "zero";
    } else {
        if ($rt) $rt = ereg_replace(" E "," e ",ucwords($rt));
            $return = ($rt) ? ($rt) : "Zero" ;
    }

    if(!$maiusculas){
        return ereg_replace(" E "," e ",ucwords($return));
    }else{
        return strtoupper($return);
    }
}
```

Exemplo:

```
$valor = 405.63;
$dim = extenso($valor);

$valor = number_format($valor, 2, ",", ".");

echo "R$ ".$valor." = ".$dim;
```

Saída

> R$ 405,63 = Quatrocentos e Cinco Reais e Sessenta e Três Centavos

Comment: É o mesmo que já havia sido postado aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106224/70 com a diferença de que foi citada a origem, e avisado que é pra valores financeiros. Além disto, o código que contém o link para esta resposta já foi mencionada nos comentários da pergunta. Sugiro sempre que copiar código de algum lugar, citar a fonte, dando o devido crédito ao autor ou site original..

Comment: Bem, no código postado eu fiz algumas alterações. Acabei de postar a fonte.

Answer (score 0):

Mas se você só precisa de algo simples e tem controle dos valores de entrada, tente isso:

```
function numero_extenso($numero=0){
    if($numero){
        $dicionario = array(
            1   => 'um',
            2   => 'dois',
            3   => 'três',
            4   => 'quatro',
            5   => 'cinco',
            6   => 'seis',
            7   => 'sete',
            8   => 'oito',
            9   => 'nove',
            10  => 'dez',
            11  => 'onze',
            12  => 'doze',
            13  => 'treze',
            14  => 'quatorze',
            15  => 'quinze',
            16  => 'dezesseis',
            17  => 'dezessete',
            18  => 'dezoito',
            19  => 'dezenove',
            20  => 'vinte',
            30  => 'trinta',
            40  => 'quarenta',
            50  => 'cinquenta',
            100 => 'cento');
        return $dicionario[$numero];
    }
}
```