# Escrever Mil e Milhoes em numero PHP

Tags: php

Bom,

Tenho os números para exemplo:

```
10
1.000
10.000
1.000.000
10.000.000
```

Preciso que num echo ele me retorne:

```
10
1 mil
10 mil
1 milhão
10 milhões
```

Encontrei e estou tentando adaptar uma função.

```
<?php
    echo valorPorExtenso(508600);

    function valorPorExtenso($valor)
    {


        $rt='';
        $singular = array("", "", "mil", "milhão", "bilhão", "trilhão", "quatrilhão");
        $plural = array("", "", "mil", "milhões", "bilhões", "trilhões","quatrilhões");

        $c = array("", "100", "200", "300", "400","500", "600", "700", "800", "900");
        $d = array("", "10", "20", "30", "40", "50","60", "70", "80", "90");
        $d10 = array("10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15","16", "17", "18", "19");
        $u = array("", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6","7", "8", "9");

        $z=0;

        $valor = number_format($valor, 2, ".", ".");
        $inteiro = explode(".", $valor);
        for($i=0;$i<count($inteiro);$i++)
            for($ii=strlen($inteiro[$i]);$ii<3;$ii++)
                $inteiro[$i] = "0".$inteiro[$i];

        // $fim identifica onde que deve se dar junção de centenas por "e" ou por "," 

    $fim = count($inteiro) - ($inteiro[count($inteiro)-1] > 0 ? 1 : 2);
    for ($i=0;$i<count($inteiro);$i++) {
        $valor = $inteiro[$i];
        $rc = (($valor > 100) && ($valor < 200)) ? "cento" : $c[$valor[0]];
        $rd = ($valor[1] < 2) ? "" : $d[$valor[1]];
        $ru = ($valor > 0) ? (($valor[1] == 1) ? $d10[$valor[2]] : $u[$valor[2]]) : "";

        $r = $rc.(($rc && ($rd || $ru)) ? " e " : "").$rd.(($rd && $ru) ? " e " : "").$ru;
        $t = count($inteiro)-1-$i;
        $r .= $r ? " ".($valor > 1 ? $plural[$t] : $singular[$t]) : "";
        if ($valor == "000")$z++; elseif ($z > 0) $z--;

        if ($r) $rt = $rt . ((($i > 0) && ($i <= $fim) && ($inteiro[0] > 0) && ($z < 1)) ? ( ($i < $fim) ? ", " : " e ") : " ") . $r;
    }

        return($rt ? $rt : "0");
    }

?>
```

Como tem no título, não quero escrever o número por extenso, quero apenas adicionar o 'mil', 'milhões', 'bilhões' e etc.

Com a função acima, esta me retornando

```
500 e 8 mil e 600
```

Preciso que me retorne

```
508600 mil
```

Outro exemplo

```
echo valorPorExtenso(102); //Retorna cento e 2
```

Preciso que me retorne

```
102
```

Me retorna

Outro exemplo (neste funcionando do jeito que preciso)

```
tenho o número 10000000
```

Está me retornando (corretamente)

```
 10 milhões
```

Comment: Já testaste alguma coisa?

Comment: Não faço nem ideia de como começar a tentar

Comment: Eu coloquei uma para financeiro, se precisar, mas acho que sua pergunta é duplicata da outra, se forem valores puramente numéricos.

Answer (score 4):

> Se não for para valores em moeda, isto já foi postado aqui:
>   [Como converter número em float para número por extenso no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99460/como-converter-n%c3%bamero-em-float-para-n%c3%bamero-por-extenso-no-php)

### Função pronta para valores financeiros:

<sub>Fonte: http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/conversao-de-valor-numerico-para-extenso-em-php</sub>

Exemplo de uso:

```
echo valorPorExtenso( 23789.37 );
```

Resultado

```
vinte e três mil, setecentos e oitenta e nove reais e trinta e sete centavos
```

O código é esse:

```
function valorPorExtenso($valor=0) {
    $singular = array("centavo", "real", "mil", "milhão", "bilhão", "trilhão", "quatrilhão");
    $plural = array("centavos", "reais", "mil", "milhões", "bilhões", "trilhões","quatrilhões");

    $c = array("", "cem", "duzentos", "trezentos", "quatrocentos","quinhentos", "seiscentos", "setecentos", "oitocentos", "novecentos");
    $d = array("", "dez", "vinte", "trinta", "quarenta", "cinquenta","sessenta", "setenta", "oitenta", "noventa");
    $d10 = array("dez", "onze", "doze", "treze", "quatorze", "quinze","dezesseis", "dezesete", "dezoito", "dezenove");
    $u = array("", "um", "dois", "três", "quatro", "cinco", "seis","sete", "oito", "nove");

    $z=0;

    $valor = number_format($valor, 2, ".", ".");
    $inteiro = explode(".", $valor);
    for($i=0;$i<count($inteiro);$i++)
        for($ii=strlen($inteiro[$i]);$ii<3;$ii++)
            $inteiro[$i] = "0".$inteiro[$i];

    // $fim identifica onde que deve se dar junção de centenas por "e" ou por "," 
    $fim = count($inteiro) - ($inteiro[count($inteiro)-1] > 0 ? 1 : 2);
    for ($i=0;$i<count($inteiro);$i++) {
        $valor = $inteiro[$i];
        $rc = (($valor > 100) && ($valor < 200)) ? "cento" : $c[$valor[0]];
        $rd = ($valor[1] < 2) ? "" : $d[$valor[1]];
        $ru = ($valor > 0) ? (($valor[1] == 1) ? $d10[$valor[2]] : $u[$valor[2]]) : "";

        $r = $rc.(($rc && ($rd || $ru)) ? " e " : "").$rd.(($rd && $ru) ? " e " : "").$ru;
        $t = count($inteiro)-1-$i;
        $r .= $r ? " ".($valor > 1 ? $plural[$t] : $singular[$t]) : "";
        if ($valor == "000")$z++; elseif ($z > 0) $z--;
        if (($t==1) && ($z>0) && ($inteiro[0] > 0)) $r .= (($z>1) ? " de " : "").$plural[$t]; 
        if ($r) $rt = $rt . ((($i > 0) && ($i <= $fim) && ($inteiro[0] > 0) && ($z < 1)) ? ( ($i < $fim) ? ", " : " e ") : " ") . $r;
    }

    return($rt ? $rt : "zero");
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/dCovAw)**.