# PHP: Como converter um numero em string?

Tags: php, html, laravel, string, cakephp

Tenho uma aplica que gera um recibo em PDF.
Porém no banco os valores tem de ser convertidos em palavras

### BD |   PHP

10  |  DEZ

15  |  QUINZE

7   |  SETE

existe alguma função que retorna a string de um numero em php ?

Comment: Nativa não existe, acho que essa pergunta resolve o problema => [Como converter número em float para número por extenso no PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99460/91)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe a classe [`NumberFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.numberformatter.php) que possibilita essa representação de números para texto.

```
$word = new \NumberFormatter('pt-BR', \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
echo $word->format(13);
// treze
```

> O segundo parâmetro da classe é que define o tipo de saída da formatação.

Esta classe depende do pacote `intl` para ser usada, verifique primeiro se este pacote esta instalado com:

```
php -m | grep intl
```

Caso já esteja instalado é só usa-la normalmente, caso não esteja instale com:

**1. Linux:** sudo apt-get install php*(version)*-intl

**2. Windows:** remova o comentario na linha com `extension=php_intl.dll` no seu php.ini e reinicie o servidor http que estiver usando

Comment: estou usando windows 10: como posso instalar ?

Comment: @alexjosesilva descomente a extensão `extension=php_intl.dll` no seu php.ini e reinicie o servidor http que estiver usando. Referência: http://dk2.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intl.installation.php#114933

Comment: coloquei a explicação que o @nunks.lol comentou no post, obrigado nunks

Comment: Interessante essa resposta +1. Fica estranho com números quebrados ex: 1.99

Comment: @rray de fato, me parece muito com alguém informando  um numero por telefone "um virgula nove nove"